# How to declare json object for datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am creating a datatable using jquery. For that I wrote a json object in my javascript inside document.ready function. Below is my code:

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
        var multistatement = [
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553701","name":"Account 1","alias":"Atlanta 1","dueDate":"10/19/2016","statementBalance":"34.60","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553702","name":"Account 2","alias":"Atlanta 2","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"14.50","statement":"3"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553703","name":"Account 3","alias":"Atlanta 3","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553704","name":"Account 4","alias":"Atlanta 4","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553705","name":"Account 5","alias":"Atlanta 5","dueDate":"09/19/2016","statementBalance":"100.50","statement":"1"}, 
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553706","name":"Account 6","alias":"Atlanta 6","dueDate":"12/19/2017","statementBalance":"18.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553707","name":"Account 7","alias":"Atlanta 7","dueDate":"01/01/2015","statementBalance":"105.50","statement":"3"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553708","name":"Account 8","alias":"Atlanta 8","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553709","name":"Account 9","alias":"Atlanta 9","dueDate":"10/07/2015","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"10"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553710","name":"Account 10","alias":"Atlanta 10","dueDate":"10/19/2016","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553711","name":"Account 11","alias":"Atlanta 11","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553712","name":"Account 12","alias":"Atlanta 12","dueDate":"04/04/2016","statementBalance":"115.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553713","name":"Account 13","alias":"Atlanta 13","dueDate":"05/19/2015","statementBalance":"25.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553714","name":"Account 14","alias":"Atlanta 14","dueDate":"03/19/2015","statementBalance":"135.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553715","name":"Account 15","alias":"Atlanta 15","dueDate":"10/19/2017","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553716","name":"Account 16","alias":"Atlanta 16","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"08.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553717","name":"Account 17","alias":"Atlanta 17","dueDate":"10/08/2015","statementBalance":"10.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553718","name":"Account 18","alias":"Atlanta 18","dueDate":"09/19/2015","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553719","name":"Account 19","alias":"Atlanta 19","dueDate":"10/05/2015","statementBalance":"15.80","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553720","name":"Account 20","alias":"Atlanta 20","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"39.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553721","name":"Account 21","alias":"Atlanta 21","dueDate":"10/21/2015","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553722","name":"Account 22","alias":"Atlanta 22","dueDate":"10/19/2016","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"}
                           ];

    generateDatatable();

    });

function generateDatatable(){
 $('#multiple-account-table').dataTable({
           "data": multistatement,
           "dom": 'it',
           "pageLength": 8,
           "language": {
               "info": "Viewing accounts 1 - _END_ of _TOTAL_ ",
               "emptyTable": "No records are available",
           },
           "columns": [
               {"data": null},
               {"data": "accountNumber"},
               {"data": "name"},
               {"data": "alias"},
               {"data": "dueDate"},
               {"data": "statementBalance"},
               {"data": null}

           ],
           "columnDefs": [
               {className: "pad-md-left-p-10 pad-top-bottom-p-10 white-active-bg mouse-link", "targets": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]},
               {
                 'targets':   0,
                 'orderable': false,
                    'render': function(data, type, full, meta) {
                         return '<input type="checkbox" name="payment-checkbox" class="multi-checkbox"/><label for="select-checkbox"></label>';
                    }
               }

       }); //End of datatable function
```

}

But this code is giving error that "multistatement is not defined". Is it wrong way to define json object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define multistatement outside the document.ready() function or else in the generateDatatable() function

Comment: I want multistatement can be accessed from any function in the same javascript file. thats why i put this inside document.ready function. If i put this in generateDatatable() then i cant access it in another function.

Comment: Main reason for that, I want to display account number value based on "statement" value. If it has only 1 statement then only it will be displayed. For that I had to write another function

Comment: If you declare outside the document.ready() it will be globally available

Comment: @Teddu functions creates scopes in JavaScript. Right now it is in the `ready's` scope.Move it outside & it would be available everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

`multistatement` is not visible in the scope of the `generateDatatable()` function. Maybe send it as the parameter to the function, like this:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        var multistatement = [
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553701","name":"Account 1","alias":"Atlanta 1","dueDate":"10/19/2016","statementBalance":"34.60","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553702","name":"Account 2","alias":"Atlanta 2","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"14.50","statement":"3"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553703","name":"Account 3","alias":"Atlanta 3","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553704","name":"Account 4","alias":"Atlanta 4","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553705","name":"Account 5","alias":"Atlanta 5","dueDate":"09/19/2016","statementBalance":"100.50","statement":"1"}, 
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553706","name":"Account 6","alias":"Atlanta 6","dueDate":"12/19/2017","statementBalance":"18.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553707","name":"Account 7","alias":"Atlanta 7","dueDate":"01/01/2015","statementBalance":"105.50","statement":"3"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553708","name":"Account 8","alias":"Atlanta 8","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553709","name":"Account 9","alias":"Atlanta 9","dueDate":"10/07/2015","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"10"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553710","name":"Account 10","alias":"Atlanta 10","dueDate":"10/19/2016","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553711","name":"Account 11","alias":"Atlanta 11","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553712","name":"Account 12","alias":"Atlanta 12","dueDate":"04/04/2016","statementBalance":"115.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553713","name":"Account 13","alias":"Atlanta 13","dueDate":"05/19/2015","statementBalance":"25.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553714","name":"Account 14","alias":"Atlanta 14","dueDate":"03/19/2015","statementBalance":"135.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553715","name":"Account 15","alias":"Atlanta 15","dueDate":"10/19/2017","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553716","name":"Account 16","alias":"Atlanta 16","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"08.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553717","name":"Account 17","alias":"Atlanta 17","dueDate":"10/08/2015","statementBalance":"10.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553718","name":"Account 18","alias":"Atlanta 18","dueDate":"09/19/2015","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553719","name":"Account 19","alias":"Atlanta 19","dueDate":"10/05/2015","statementBalance":"15.80","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553720","name":"Account 20","alias":"Atlanta 20","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"39.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553721","name":"Account 21","alias":"Atlanta 21","dueDate":"10/21/2015","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"},
                           {"accountNumber":"131-202553722","name":"Account 22","alias":"Atlanta 22","dueDate":"10/19/2016","statementBalance":"15.50","statement":"1"}
                           ];

    generateDatatable(multistatement);

    });

function generateDatatable(multistatement){
 $('#multiple-account-table').dataTable({
           "data": multistatement,
           "dom": 'it',
           "pageLength": 8,
           "language": {
               "info": "Viewing accounts 1 - _END_ of _TOTAL_ ",
               "emptyTable": "No records are available",
           },
           "columns": [
               {"data": null},
               {"data": "accountNumber"},
               {"data": "name"},
               {"data": "alias"},
               {"data": "dueDate"},
               {"data": "statementBalance"},
               {"data": null}

           ],
           "columnDefs": [
               {className: "pad-md-left-p-10 pad-top-bottom-p-10 white-active-bg mouse-link", "targets": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]},
               {
                 'targets':   0,
                 'orderable': false,
                    'render': function(data, type, full, meta) {
                         return '<input type="checkbox" name="payment-checkbox" class="multi-checkbox"/><label for="select-checkbox"></label>';
                    }
               }

       }); //End of datatable function
```